# Cannot invoke"java.security.cert.X509Certificate.getEncoded() error while exporting SSL Certificate BurpSuit

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, burp

I have burp suite installed on windows 10, when I try to export certificate, it says:

```
Failed to export certificate: java.lang.NullPointerException:Cannot invoke"java.security.cert.X509Certificate.getEncoded()"because "burp.r2n.P"is null
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ7MK.jpg)

export certificate for burp suite